# Wrapper for tr with Vue.js DataTable

Tags: jquery, vue.js, datatable, wrapper

I have a table with 2 `<tr>` in it. I need to wrap this 2 `<tr>` and do the `v-for` in the wrap. But the `v-for` on `<tbody>` break the datatable.

## Actual code :

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="data_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody v-for="item in items">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.T }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.T }}</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

## Tried :

```
<table class="table table-striped" id="data_table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
    <div v-for="item in items">
        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.A }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>{{ item.T }}</td>
            <td>{{ item.T }}</td>
        </tr>
    </div>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

But the div break the datatable.

Thank's for answering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of `div` use `template`.  This will loop the items in your array without creating an extra element as a wrapper